# How to pass `this` pointer from outer class to a member structure?

Tags: c++

I have a template class as given below. I am getting an error "ElemsCombineCycle has no member named `_iterator`" at the line `auto comb = ElemsCombineCycle ();` The reason is that the `this` inside the struct is not pointing to the outer class.

```
template < typename G, typename A, typename Gt >
class WIt final : public WCV< G, Gt > {
  private:
    InterIt& _iterator;
  public:
    using Elems = std::vector<AVC>;

    struct ElemsCombineCycle {
      Node head;
      const WNT& cycle_n = this->_iterator.nest(head);

      template<typename Iterator>
      Elems operator()(const Elems acc, const Iterator& it) const {
      Node pred = *it;
      Elems post_vector;
      post_vector = this->_iterator.post(pred);

      if (this->_iterator.nest(pred) <= cycle_n) {

      Elems result;
      for (auto a : acc) {
        for (auto n : post_vector) {
          A pre = a.get_value();
             result.push_back(AVC(pre.join(this->_iterator.analyze(head, n.get_value()))));

          }
        }
       return result;
     }
    else
       return acc;
   }
 };

 void visit(const WCT& c) override {
   Node head = c.head();
   A pre = A::bottom();
   Elems pre_vector;
   pre_vector.push_back(AVC(pre));

   const WNT& cycle_n = this->_iterator.nest(head);

   this->_iterator.notify(head);

   auto comb = ElemsCombineCycle ();
   comb.head = head;
   Elems new_pre_vector = std::accumulate(Gt::p_begin(head), Gt::p_end(head), pre_vector, comb);
  }
 };
```

Please tell me how to solve this error and pass `this` from outer class to the inner struct.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What do you expect from `const WNT& cycle_n = this->_iterator.nest(head);` in inner struct?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I have removed all commands that is not related to `_iterator` and not necessary for the `std::accumulate` line. Apart from that I have not provided the type definitions because they are not necessary for this error.

Comment: What do you expect `const WNT& cycle_n = this->_iterator.nest(head);` to do?

Comment: @Jarod42 I used the line in struct so that I don't need to pass the `cycle_n` from `visit`. I think that I can pass this from `visit`. But I need to use `this->_iterator` for other uses in the struct.

Comment: @world_of_science Inside the nested struct, `this` points to the instance of that nested struct, period. If you need access to an instance of the outer class, you need to pass a pointer/reference to it.

Comment: @Angew Please tell me how to pass this reference of the outer class to this nested struct.

Comment: The type definitions and the main function are necessary for others to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is not Java.

Declaring a struct inside the declaration of a class does not give the inner a pointer to the outer, there is no `WIt` instance associated with a `ElemsCombineCycle` instance, they can exist independently.

It looks like you are trying to write an equivalent to a lambda, so just write a lambda. Those *do* have special treatment for `this`

```
void visit(const WCT& c) override {
   Node head = c.head();
   A pre = A::bottom();
   Elems pre_vector;
   pre_vector.push_back(AVC(pre));

   const WNT& cycle_n = this->_iterator.nest(head);

   this->_iterator.notify(head);

   auto comb = [this, cycle_n, head](const Elems acc, const Iterator& it) {
      Node pred = *it;
      Elems post_vector = this->_iterator.post(pred);

      if (this->_iterator.nest(pred) <= cycle_n) {

      Elems result;
      for (auto a : acc) {
        for (auto n : post_vector) {
          A pre = a.get_value();
             result.push_back(AVC(pre.join(this->_iterator.analyze(head, n.get_value()))));

          }
        }
       return result;
     }
    else
       return acc;
   };
   Elems new_pre_vector = std::accumulate(Gt::p_begin(head), Gt::p_end(head), pre_vector, comb);
  }
```

Comment: They can exist independently as you said but still the struct needs the commands that use `this` now. Please suggest a way to pass the `this` pointer to the struct.

Comment: The `const Iterator& it` is not correct because there is no `Iterator` type. There was `template<typename Iterator>` before the function.

Comment: Also there is an error `error: expected ‘{’ before ‘const’`.